# Does openssl3.1 support UEFI target with FIPS enabled?

Tags: openssl, mingw, msys2, uefi, fips

I am trying to build openssl 3.1 in FIPS mode for the UEFI target. But the config option enable-fips as defined in the documentation does not define the flag FIPS_MODULE for UEFI targets. Also, I notice that Makefile after configuring for UEFI does not have the required scripts. I am building in windows with mingw environment.

Tried other targets like Cygwin which seems to build fine with enable-fips